# Trying to rollup Vue with TypeScript and vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, decorator, rollup

As the title says, and I don't have any code example right now, how is it so impossible to combine Rollup, Vue, Typescript and vue-property-decorator?
Whenever I try it wants to add vue-property-decorator as an external dependency. Any link to a working solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to provide some code example so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah I wish I could have, but we gave up. It never got transformed into JavaScript. It might work today with a smarter Typescript version. :)